# The bot should sent a message but it doesn't

Tags: discord.py

So I got this script, and it doesn't work but does not write any errors in console. Just doesn't send message at all.

```
async def run(ctx,channel,arg1,arg2,arg3):
    color = arg3
    if color in color_table:
      actual_color = getattr(discord.Colour, color)()
      embed=discord.Embed(title=arg1, description=arg2, color=actual_color)
      embed.set_footer(text="Powered by T.A.D.S.")
      channel_id = channel.id
      channel = discord.utils.get(ctx.guild.text_channels, id=int(channel_id))
      await channel.send(embed=embed)
    else:
      await ctx.channel.send("This color doesn't exist in discord databeses. Type !colours to show all colors that are available.")
```

I want the bot to send a message to specified channel but it does nothing.

Comment: Do you want the message to be sent to a specified channel? So you'd have to add the channel id in your message? Or should it be sent to the channel you use the command in?

Comment: Is this your full code? If it is, you need to `import` the discord.py library and add some other discord.py specific code to run it. See https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/quickstart.html.

Comment: Also, please see [ask], [help/on-topic] and [how to ask](/help/how-to-ask)